# Consume a list of natural numbers in DrRacket and return values in the list that have zeros in the tens column

Tags: list, filtering, racket

Write a function (zero-ten L) that consumes a (listof Nat) and returns all the values in L that have a zero in the 10s column.

For example, 109, 4000 and 24601 all have a zero in the 10s column, but 1011, 42, and 9 do not.

Comment: Is there a more specific problem you're having with what you've tried so far?

Comment: I'll be fully honest with you, I'm baffled with this question. I didn't even know where to start. How do i even identify the value of the 10s column. I thought maybe converting the number to a list(char) then identifying the second last character but that didn't seem right to me. Am I missing something here or am I just being oblivious.

Comment: "I thought maybe converting the number to a list(char) then identifying the second last character but" Is there anything preventing you from doing that? Did you not try it before saying it doesn't seem right?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove last digit and check if the rest is divisible by 10. Then use [filter](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._filter%29%29):

```
(define (divisible? n d) (= 0 (remainder n d)))

(define (zero-ten n)
  (let ((n1 (quotient n 10)))
    (and (positive? n1)
         (divisible? n1 10))))

(define (filter-zero-ten xs)
  (filter zero-ten xs))
```

Now `(filter-zero-ten '(109 4000 24601 1011 42 9))` returns `'(109 4000 24601)`